# Binary Matrix Math

Tags: matrices

I'm new learner into Matrix and I want to know how to write the binary Matrix of equivalence relation

$xRn \leftrightarrow x ≡ n \bmod(3)$

for number $0-9$

I Know the value of this relation will be in ($0$ or $1$ or $2$) and the equivalence relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive but I'm very confused about writing the matrix.

Comment: I think your question is not using vocabulary in the common way.  Please provide examples so that we can help.

Comment: I want to represent the equivalence relation in a matrix for integers from 0 to 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are asking for a $10\times10$ matrix $A$ with entries $A_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$ (where for convenience $i$ and $j$ go from $0$ to $9$ rather than $1$ to $10$) such that:

- $A_{ij}=1$ if $i\equiv j\pmod 3$; and
- $A_{ij}=0$ if $i\not\equiv j\pmod 3$.

Such a matrix $A$ is just a representation of the binary relation "equivalent modulo 3". But since a relation either holds or doesn't hold, the entries of $A$ will be in $\{0,1\}$, not in $\{0,1,2\}$.

The first three rows of $A$ will look like this:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you dear I'm asking about that and what about the other rows It will be all 0

Comment: The other rows will not be all zero. For example, the next row will at least have a 1 at the beginning again because $3\equiv0\pmod3$. Then there will be two 0s before the next 1, and so on. Another way to work out the rest of the matrix is just to continue the pattern of diagonal lines of 1s.